# getTitle() using web URL, rather than webView.getTitle();

Tags: android, url, android-webview

I am trying to get the title of a webpage in a webView, I cannot just call `webView.getTitle();` because even in `onPageStarted()` the `WebView` has not yet received the title. I do however already have the URL for the webpage that being loaded, so if theres something like `getTitle(url);` That would be exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using the URL, you'd have to load the document over the network, parse it, and then take the title—which you probably don't want to do yourself.

I think what you actually need is this: set a custom **[WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)** for your WebView, and implement **`onPageFinished()`** for that; the WebView instance passed to that method has title set. [**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8193479/56285) has a complete example.

Comment: yeh, I am already using onPageFinished() for this,  but its too slow, I wanted the title as soon as the page started loading. I may just parse the html myself, thanks anyway.

Comment: @timeshift117: You could try WebChromeClient and its `onReceivedTitle()`  which [according to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12154530/56285) is quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Its not the best way but it works(Its about 70% faster):

```
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
         {  

            if(progress > 30 && progress < 41){
            // using boolean:lock to call this method once everytime
             if(!lock){  
                // get the Title by web.getTitle();
             lock = true;
            }                    
            }

            if(progress > 40){ lock = false;    }

  }});
```

OR another way(Even Faster) :

```
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
         {  

            if(OldPageTitle != web.getTitle()){//getTitle has the newer Title 
            // get the Title
            OldPagerTitle = web.getTitle();
            }                    



  }});
```