# Get Title, Description and image from URL

Tags: android, html, seo

In my android app, I have list of different blog URL, and I want to make google like card view.

I just want to know that how can I get info, like "Title", "Description", & "Image URL" etc. from the URL only.

Just like when I put some link in facebook or whatsapp they get the above information.

So how can I achieve it?

Comment: Download the content at the URL. Parse it using the appropriate parser for the MIME type (RSS, Atom, etc.). Collect your information from the parsed results.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the web page title with this(This answer is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193239/how-to-get-loaded-web-page-title-in-android-webview)):

You'll have to use a custom WebViewClient to get this done. You will override the onPageFinished() method so when a new page finishes loading you can set the webview to the appropriate title.

Below is a sample implementation of the above:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mwebview);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        ExperimentingActivity.this.setTitle(view.getTitle());
    }
});
```

But the description and image url is whole different story. Most webpages are different from each other and when you are getting a part of a webpage with a code, the code may be insufficient to work for another website. Yet, you can use a library like [goose](https://github.com/milosmns/goose?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4163) for parse a web page. What goose does is basically analyse a webpage and get the parts of that webpage that is most likely to be wanted.