# Android Webview onReceivedTitle not called on page reload

Tags: android, android-webview, chromium

I've been trying to inject some js into a webview in my app. Have been using
`onReceivedTitle` method of `WebChromeClient` since I want to execute the js while the page is loading.

This has been working until now. But recently, I observed that `onReceivedTitle` is not called we reload the webpage, similar to `window.location.reload`.

Firstly, I can't understand why it shouldn't be called. Or it should be and it's a bug?

Secondly, now that we know it's not called, where else can I inject by js?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is the issue : https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/web_contents/web_contents_impl.cc?l=4760

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is a bug in chromium. I worked around this by injecting my scripts on `onPageFinished` method of `WebviewClient.`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is not considered an Android bug, but rather a ***Chrome or Chromium-based WebView bug***. It should be reported to http://crbug.com/.

I'll suggest you to try a workaround with custom **WebViewClient**:

You'll have to use a custom WebViewClient to get this done. You will override the onPageFinished() method so when a new page finishes loading you can set the webview to the appropriate title.

Below is a sample implementation of the above:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mwebview);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        ExperimentingActivity.this.setTitle(view.getTitle());
    }
});
```

This answer here will prove to be useful:https://stackoverflow.com/a/8193479/9080948

Comment: yeah, that's what I did actually, with a small difference. Instead of setting the title, I directly injected the script

Comment: could you please share your code to give a better picture of your question.And are you using WebViewClient now?