# How to programatically save website title and URL for speed dial buttons like opera or Firefox?

Tags: android

I'm creating a browser with a start page and edittext that that directs you to the actual browsing section of the app when a URL is entered. On the start page I also have 5 working static speed dial keys in a gridview. I have placed an add button which opens a dialog box with two edittexts, one for the title and one for the URL along with two buttons, create and cancel. After getting this far I'm stuck. I tried to add another Room database and tried to set it up similar to how I have my tabs but that didn't work at all. I think I need to somehow be able to dynamically add an image button that saves the website URL and title and possibly grab it's favicon. At this point at least the button, title and URL, and I can figure out the favicon later. Can anyone give me a little insight as to how this would work? I can post code if needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get loaded web page title in Android WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193239/how-to-get-loaded-web-page-title-in-android-webview)

Comment: This possible duplicate isn't nearly close to what I'm trying to achieve. I need to fetch the title only to go with the URL, favicon and added button. The title and favicon shall represent the speed dial button, all of which I'm trying to figure how to add programatically on button press.